# Excel IF Function (3 Values)

Tags: excel, function, if-statement

Please help me out with this one in Excel.
I used this one but does not work

```
=IF(Q67 < 6, "D",  IF(Q67 > 6  < 11, "M", IF(Q67  > 10, "E", "")))
```

This should go like this:

E- Greater than 11

D - Less than 6

M - Greater than 5 but not equal to 11

Your answers will be appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: What about blanks? If Q67 is blank?

Answer (score 1):

First issue, the ranges overlap...

So, assuming my correction is valid you could try:

```
=if(Q67>11,"E",if(Q67<6,"D","M"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=IF(Q67 < 6, "D",  IF(Q67 < 11, "M",  "E"))
'testing if Q67 is not blank as well
=IF(Q67="", "", IF(Q67 < 6, "D",  IF(Q67 < 11, "M",  "E")))
```

If Q67 is not less than 6 it fails the first test and moves on to the second. You don't need to check if Q67 is greater or equal to 6 at that point because if it wasn't greater or equal to 6 it wouldn't be there in the first place.

However, it may be important to understand how two conditions work.

```
=IF(Q67 < 6, "D",  IF(AND(Q67 >= 6, Q67 < 11), "M", IF(Q67  >= 11, "E", "")))
```